# How to effectively distribute points on plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry, html5-canvas, graph-algorithm

I have a plane (screen) with its width and height (monitor resolution, not square). And I'd like to distribute points on that plane with the (approximately) same distance from each other.

For example:

- 1 point will be in the middle,
- 2 points will be in the middle of y axis, and x axis will be divided by 3
- 3 points may be like triangle, but if sceen is wide enough, thay can be alighned in same y
- 4 like second part of above, or as rectangle..
- etc to 8 points max

Is there any algorithm for this?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:** same distance from each other and from plane border

**EDIT2:** I compute centers of mass for groups of objects on which behavior I simulate on plane.

Comment: If the subdivisions are all rectangles then you can iterate through each sub-rectangle and find a random point.

Comment: @DoSparKot just edited question. So, from 2 points: divide plane into rectangles and find any random point in rectangles? That will be rough approximation, but if I use centers of those rectangles? What do you think?

Comment: `same distance from each other and from plane border` then they've to be the center of each rectangle. It's gets easier and quicker.

Comment: @DoSparKot :D Thank you, but what about even number of points?

Comment: for even number of points or for rectangle with even side lengths you can't have a point in the center exactly. However equidistant property spread them apart nicely across screen.

Comment: @DoSparKot I compute centers of mass for groups of objects on which behavior I simulate on plane. And now I found some interesting articles about it so in short time when I implement it I'll post answer.

Comment: Please add that info to question. It's a vital info for the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to everybody for suggestions which helped me to define my problem better and to find best solution to my problem.

Now I am using **Centroidal Voronoi tessellation** which according to Wikipedia: *"In geometry, a centroidal Voronoi tessellation (CVT) is a special type of Voronoi tessellation or Voronoi diagrams. A Voronoi tessellation is called centroidal when the generating point of each Voronoi cell is also its mean (center of mass). It can be viewed as an optimal partition corresponding to an optimal distribution of generators."*

Its very fast and there is implementation in D3js library for javascript which I am using.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the precision you want:

- You can get a stochasticaly correct answer by Poisson disk sampling. Specifically, a Poisson disk sampling is a random sampling such that no points are closer than a specified radius. Such thing can be efficiently (linear time) implemented in high dimension - e.g. : the c++ code from Robert Bridson : http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/download/curlnoise.tar.gz  implementing his paper http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf
- You can really optimize for the position of the points. This leads to Lloyd algorithms and similar optimization procedures : Compute the Voronoi diagram of an initial set of points, and move these points the the centroid of their Voronoi cell. This can also be done very efficiently, and can be sped up by using a Newton's method rather than a Lloyd iteration.
  Ultimately, if your domain is a square, you should obtain an hexagonal grid (which minimizes the function above).

If you only need approximate results, I'd suggest the first approach which should be much faster.

Comment: I am using your second suggestion. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of points, the result is going to look like an hexagonal grid:

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/hex_grid/hex_grid.html

Otherwise it gets more complicated. One algorithm that works very nicely (but is probably overkill), is to do a physics simulation where points are particles that repel each other. Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nvr2csxRE) that does the same on a sphere for an example.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Not for physics repulsion simulation.

Dividing a plane into rectangle is easier to process. For rectangles with even side-lengths you can't have a point in the center exactly. However equidistant property spread them apart nicely across screen.

Simple program in PHP to illustrate this:

```
<?php 
$x_min = 1; $x_max = 1366;

$y_min = 1; $y_max = 768;

$x_div_count = 5;
$y_div_count = 5;

$x_div_len = (integer)round(($x_min + $x_max) / $x_div_count);
$y_div_len = (integer)round(($y_min + $y_max) / $y_div_count);

$x_mid_offset = (integer)round($x_div_len /2);
$y_mid_offset = (integer)round($y_div_len /2); 

$x_offset = $x_mid_offset;
for ($idx =0; $idx < $x_div_count; $idx ++) {

    $y_offset = $y_mid_offset;
    for ($jdx =0; $jdx < $y_div_count; $jdx ++) {

        $points_dist[] = array ('x' => $x_offset, 'y' => $y_offset);

        $y_offset += $y_div_len;
    }
    $x_offset += $x_div_len;
}

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

PS: If you can handle sub-pixel rendering then go with float point values. Such points are often to be blurry yet good overall effects.